# The difference between front() and begin()

Tags: c++, stl

What is the difference between the `front()` and `begin()` functions that appears in many STL containers?

Comment: `front()` is identical to `*begin()`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`begin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/begin/) returns an iterator that can be used to iterate through the collection, while [`front()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/front/) just returns a reference to the first element of the collection.

Comment: +1 Just to make things more explicit (or maybe complicate): `&c.front() == &*c.begin()` for any container that has at least one element. Comparing the *address-of* the expressions is used to demonstrate that it is not the *values* that are the same, but the *objects* (i.e. `c.front()` yields a reference to the same object that dereferencing the begin iterator `*c.begin()`).

Answer (score 5):

`front()` returns a reference to the first element, `begin()` returns an iterator to it.

Note that you shouldn't call `front` on an empty container, but it's OK to call `begin` as long as you don't dereference the iterator that `begin` returns.

Answer (score 2):

The `front` member returns a reference to the first member of a list or vector. The `begin` function returns an iterator (which is more like a pointer) initialized to the first member of a list, map, or vector.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/begin/ (literally the first google result for "vector::begin"):

> Notice that unlike member `vector::front`, which returns a reference to the first element, this function returns a random access iterator.