# Is the code valid. If i want to display first element? if not then what will s.begin() return?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to display first element inserted into a vector.Can i use the begin() to access it?

```
 vector<int>s;
 s.push_back(5);
 cout<<s.begin();
```

Comment: Why not compile it and see?

Comment: If you want to know what the member functions do **[consult the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)**

Comment: Try to ran it.But gave me an error.

Comment: Do you know how to use *iterators*? Have you used iterators before, e.g. in a loop? Perhaps you should [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read, because this is something that such a book would tell you.

Comment: You may be looking for [`std::vector::front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front).

Comment: "Try to ran it.But gave me an error." Well.. it's probably not valid then :p `std::vector::begin` returns an iterator, where the indirection operator is overloaded. `std::cout << *s.begin( );`

Comment: answer is No. [vector - begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) and [what is an Iterator?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.2B.2B)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The difference between front() and begin()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303110/the-difference-between-front-and-begin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, the `begin()` member function returns a pointer (or iterator) to the front (a lot of the time, anyways).

You can access the first element with `begin()`, but you have to dereference it (like a pointer) first:

```
cout << *s.begin(); // 5
```

Here is a demo: https://repl.it/JQiU/0

Answer (score 0):

Access with the `std::vector::operator[]`.

```
vector<int>s;
s.push_back(5);
cout << s[0];
```